# ListView change text size in Metro Apps

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, xaml, winrt-xaml

I'm not sure why I'm finding it so difficult to find information on this, but I have no clue how to change the item text size of each item inside a list view.
I don't know if I'm googling the right thing but I can't seem to find an answer to this, or really anything in general about styling elements properly.

I tried doing FontSize in the ListView but it changes nothing.
Sorry for such a mundane question but I can't find anything about this.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change listview item style i.e itemcontainerstyle like this

```
   <ListView>
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="25"/>
                <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe Ui Light"/>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ListView>
```

or you can edit listviewitem style template also which is available on Msdn.

Comment: @Heena Patil in 'values/styles' folder from my Android project??

Comment: @KryNaC sorry i didnt understand your problem.

Comment: @Heena Patil where you change this code? In which folder is the file where you have to put this code?

Comment: are you working with xamrin app ? this is xaml file .

Comment: @Heena Patil not, I am not working with xamrin app =(

Comment: @KryNaC I am working in wpf application ...you can write this code in MainWindow.xaml like this http://prntscr.com/6g7b8c ...this answer is for xaml/wpf...this code will not work in android project.